# Spring cloud config returns old configutaion

Tags: spring-cloud, spring-cloud-config, spring-cloud-bus

I'm using spring cloud config together with spring cloud bus.
I set up a webhook from my git repository (hosted in bitbucket) to notify the config server when a push occurs. In order to reduce throughput and use a minimal caching I set the refresh rate for 2 minutes:

```
spring.cloud.config.server.git.refresh-rate=120
```

Now when I push to the repository, the config server is being notified via the webhook and send a message to the clients. The client is asking for the configuration again from the server, but because the refresh rate is set to two minutes, and the notifications chain is faster the configuration server returns the previous configuration.

Is there a way to cancel the refresh rate on a webhook (a request to /monitor)? Maybe other way to overcome this issue?

Comment: no there is not.

Comment: I have the same problem, how did you solve the it ?